# Escape character inserted '\' while returning json from api node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to create on simple api using node.js
Here is the code`var express=require("express");

```
var app =express();

var fs=require("fs")
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(express.static('public'));



var router = express.Router();
var port = process.env.PORT || 8081; 
//Read file from JSON file


router.get('/', function(req, res) {    

fs.readFile('routes.JSON','utf8',function (err,data) {
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
   console.log(data);
   res.json(data);
});


});

app.use('/api', router);


app.listen(port);
console.log('Listening to ' + port);`

Here I'm reading a json file routes.JSON and return the value to http://127.0.0.1:8081/api

I'm expecting the output `
{
  "placeid": 123,
  "timings": {
    "time":"12/03/2014:09:12",
      "geocode": {
        "long":"37.423021",
        "lat":"122.083739",
        "toLocation":"Vaikom"
      }

  }

}`
```

But it gives the output like this

"{\r\n  \"placeid\": 123,\r\n  \"timings\": {\r\n    \"time\":\"12/03/2014:09:12\",\r\n      \"geocode\": {\r\n        \"long\":\"37.423021\",\r\n        \"lat\":\"122.083739\",\r\n        \"toLocation\":\"Chempu\"\r\n      }\r\n    \r\n  }\r\n  \r\n}"

I was able to write json to console without '\'.

Comment: JSON.parse(data) will do the trick

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add JSON.parse function when you return data like this.

```
res.json(JSON.parse(data));
```

When you are reading from file its basically of string datatype. When you output to the console its prints whatever was in file giving you an illusion that its a json object but its string. Try printing typeof data also to console, you would understand.

Comment: Or `res.send(data)`, and set the `Content-Type` header.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the headers in the postman, I had the same issue but later I realized that I used content-Type- application/*something* instead of "Content-Type"-"application/JSON", The issue was resolved after changing the header to application/JSON.